# How to download a directory and its contents using PSFTP?

Tags: ssh, putty, sftp, psftp

I'm using PSFTP and am looking to download two directories and all of their subdirectories and place them else where on my server.

I would think it would be as simple as

```
get dirname c:\localdirname
get dirname2 c:\localdirname2
```

But I get read permission errors, however, if I specify one file at a time, it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  LCD to the local directory I want to save to, cd to the remote directory I need, then use mget *

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **`get -r <dirname>`**.

To move directories within the same server, you can also use `mv <oldname> <newname>`.